# PS3 Destiny marks

Tags: ps3, destiny

How do I earn marks driving me crazy I'm level 14 ? I've tried all ways to get but only get reputation instead of marks any clues peeps

Comment: The whole game kinda starts when you're level 20. Don't worry about anything until you reach lv20.

Comment: Edited my answer on the linked duplicate to also answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't earn Vanguard or Crucible marks until level 18.  At that point, you'll get them for doing various things.  Vanguard marks are earned by playing PvE, while you'll get Crucible marks for playing PvP.

One of the fastest ways of getting them is doing the daily/weekly featured challenges/playlists, which are down the left hand side of the main map screen while in orbit.

Answer (score 0):

**Vanguard Marks:**

Vanguard Marks are obtained only after you reach level 18. Once that is accomplished, you earn then by:

> **1.**  Completing public events.
>
> **2.**  Completing strike missions.
>
> **3.**  Completing your first public event each day.

**Crucible Marks:**

Like Vanguard Marks, Crucible Marks are also only obtained after reaching level 18. After that you can earn Crucible Marks by completing PvP sessions

> **Note:** You can only earn a maximum of 100 Vanguard Marks and Crucible Marks between weekly resets, which is at Tuesday, 9am UTC. Also marks cap at 200 for both Crucible and Vanguard.

[Source](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188716/what-are-the-different-currencies-and-how-are-they-earned)